# Ошибка в git: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe;: No such file or directory

Tags: git

Начала знакомиться с git и уже проблема.
Нужно было ввести в консоль: `$ git help config` после ввода выскакивает ошибка:
[image]

Как я понял он не может найти cmd, хотя я уже в %PATH% понатыкал все пути к cmd.exe
[image: PATH]
[image: PATH1]
[image: PATH3]

Подскажите как решить проблему, желательно пошагово.

Comment: Нет, он пытается найти вовсе не cmd.exe. Откуда у вас в ComSpec взялась точка с запятой?

Comment: Она сама ставится, если зайти в "изменить" ее там нету

Comment: `cmd.exe` — это файл, а не каталог. Уберите его из переменных окружения.

Comment: @0andriy Разницы нету, это я просто на всякий случай закинул туда, даже если убрать, все равно не работает.

Comment: А вы git установили? Если да, то как?

Comment: @zed Да, git установлен, я даже смог проект выложить на github. Устанавливал через установщик на Windows

Comment: Если в консоли написать `git` он запускается?

Comment: @zed Да, и в GitBash и в cmd все работает

Comment: Тогда это вероятно проблемы команды `git help` - справка недоустановлена или ещё что.

Comment: @zed Ну можно сказать что проблема не критичная, просто интересно почему такая ошибка.